# Transmission of beliefs through networks

Tags: social-psychology, reference-request, social-networks

I recall seeing references to studies about the spreading of true/false beliefs through social networks. I think this research tends to be grounded in game theory or evolutionary theory (like gene transmission), but I could be wrong.

Can anyone direct me to the research on this or point to seminal papers? I took a quick look at Google Scholar, but it's not clear where to start.  I'm interested in theory papers, but I'm especially interested in empirical work.  Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: One possibility is "memetics" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memetics, another is "small-world" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-world_experiment, and possibly "social dynamics" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_dynamics

Comment: This question is dealt with in a book called "The Half Life of Facts" by Samuel Arbesman. I might answer your question directly soon.

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg  I think memetics is definitely a good keyword here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check out [*Networks, Crowds, and Markets*](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/networks-book/networks-book.pdf) (David Easley and Jon Kleinberg, 2010), esp. chapters 16 and 19.